# About an embedding

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Previously I saw a sentence in a text which stated
PSL(n, q) is isomorphic to a subgroup of PSL(n+1, q).
I can not prove this result or show that it is incorrect. Could you please answer about it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is false. For example ${\rm PSL}(3,7)$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of ${\rm PSL}(4,7)$.

There is a natural embedding of ${\rm SL}(n-1,q)$ into ${\rm SL}(n,q)$. If $\gcd(n-1,q) \ne 1$ then the image is not isomorphic to ${\rm PSL}(n-1,q)$, and since $n-1$ is coprime to $n$, factoring out the centre of ${\rm SL}(n,q)$, which has order $\gcd(n,q)$. does not change this image. So this natural embedding does no induce and embedding ${\rm PSL}(n-1,q) \to {\rm PSL}(n,q)$.

This does not prove that it does not arise as a subgroup in some other way, which would have to be as the quotient of an irreducible representation of ${\rm PSL}(n-1,q)$ of dimension $n$. When $n-1=2$ and $n=3$, there is such a representation coming from the isomorphism ${\rm PSL}(2,q) \cong \Omega(3,q)$. For $n \ge 4$ there is in general no such representation, although you need to be familiar the theory of representations of groups of Lie type in natural characteristic to know that.